# Why I'm getting exeption (file not found) when passing the location of the file testing but it does work with the same file using Postman?

Tags: java, mockito, postman, apache-tika

I'm using Postman to run my Java project which runs as expected pasing a directory file as an input and then getting an output file, but when I'm using Mockito with Unit Test to test the actual project Tika is throwing an exeption of "File not found".

I'm confused because I did even copy and paste the file's location from Postman to my test with no results and also tried to pass the same file harcoded inside of my class to test with no results as well. I also tried to change the logic of my code with no results. At the moment I haven't got the full path of the file as in Postman but it doesn't work with the full path either. I'm trying to test the following classes:

This is my RestHandler class which is called from Postman as well:

```
public class RestHandler {
private final ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;
private final BasicFileHandlerService basicFileHandlerService;
private final TikaService tikaService;
private final AmazonRekognitionAsync amazonRekognitionAsync;


public void processFilesInFolder(String pickUpFolder) {
    //This will print out the file's path 
    System.out.println("ListOfFiles!!!!! : " + pickUpFolder);
    //Here is where I get the exeption
    List<File> allFile = basicFileHandlerService.getAllFile(pickUpFolder);
    for (int i = 0; i < allFile.size() ; i++) {
        String st = String.valueOf(allFile.get(i)).replace("%", " ");
        File file = new File(st);
        allFile.set(i, file);
    }

    allFile.forEach(file -> {
        System.out.println("This is the file: " + file);
        //If I call Tika's method I do get the same exeption as well
        TikaResult extractText = tikaService.extractText(file);
        String fileNoPath = file.getName().substring(String.valueOf(file).indexOf("\\")-2);
```

This is my Tika service class:

```
public class TikaService {

private final Parser parser;

public TikaResult extractText(File file) {
    //This doesn't get called because the file I'm passing exists
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("does not exist");
    }

    String s = "";
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();


    try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
        ContentHandler contentHandler = new BodyContentHandler(out);

        parser.parse(new FileInputStream(file), contentHandler, metadata, parseContext);
        s = new String(out.toByteArray());

        boolean shouldThrowException = false;
    } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

This is my test:

```
@InjectMocks
RestHandler restHandler;
TikaService tikaService;

@Test
public void contextLoads() {

    File fileForTikaService = new File("src/test/java/TestFiles/Johnson_-_TestTXT.txt");

    restHandler.processFilesInFolder("src/test/java/TestFiles/Johnson_-_TestTXT.txt");
    TikaResult extractText = tikaService.extractText(fileForTikaService);

    File outputTestFile = new File("src/test/java/resources/resultFiles/Johnson_-_TestTXT.txt.csv");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the test has a different working directory. What does `System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());` give you in the test? Does it differ from the normal execution? Also where does it succeed and where does it fail? I couldn't really tell where exactly your problem lies.

Comment: I did discover I was mocking the wrong classes, the Resthandler one shouldn't be mocked because is the main class from which I'm going to rum my application, I'm going to answer my own question to clarify and hopefully will answer someone's else with the same problem. Thanks anayway :)

Answer (score 0):

I realised I was mocking the wrong class, in my case the "restHandler" class is the main class which I'm executing my code from using Postman so that class shouldn't be mocked. On the other hand the classes to be mocked are the services(they are the main reason why I need to mock because with a normal test wouldn't work.

This is my working test:

```
@Mock
BasicFileHandlerService basicFileHandlerService;
TikaService tikaService;
ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;
AmazonRekognitionAsync amazonRekognitionAsync;

List<File> files = new LinkedList<>();
List<String[]> rows = new LinkedList<>();

String filePath = ("src\\test\\java\\TestFiles");
String fileContents = "John Johnson is a judge on the Washington State Supreme Court.\n" + "Johnson has been a judge for 14 years.\n";
File fileToVerify = new File("src/test/java/resources/resultFiles/Johnson_-_TestTXT.txt.csv");

@Test
public void OutputTest() throws IOException {

    RestHandler restHandler = new RestHandler(applicationConfig, basicFileHandlerService, tikaService, amazonRekognitionAsync);

    int countFiles = new File(filePath).list().length;

    int alreadyExecuted = 0;

    File outputFile = new File("CSVOutput/Annotations.csv");
    outputFile.delete();
    outputFile.createNewFile();

    //Call to the real class to test
    restHandler.processFilesInFolder(filePath);

    doCallRealMethod().when(basicFileHandlerService).findLine(any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class), any(List.class), any(int.class), any(int.class));
    basicFileHandlerService.findLine("Johnson", fileContents,"Johnson_-_TestTXT.txt", rows, countFiles, alreadyExecuted);

    String outputFileContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(outputFile.toPath()));
    String resultFileContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(fileToVerify.toPath()));

    Assert.assertEquals(outputFileContents, resultFileContents);
    System.out.println(resultFileContents);

}
```